Is it possible to use iPhone 14 with very fast internet as a hotspot via lightning-to-ethernet?
I have a managed ethernet switch with dozens of devices connected and iPhone 14 with very fast internet.
Is it possible to allow iPhone to share mobile internet via lightning-to-ethernet adapter with all devices connected to a single switch?
